# How to hide grid labels without redefining the grid style?

Tags: pstricks, options

I want to hide the grid labels without redefining the grid style, is it possible?
Note: Redefining the grid style only for hiding the grid labels seems to be an overkill solution.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
%\newpsstyle{gridstyle}{gridlabels=0,% other redefinition goes here!}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom,gridlabels=0](8,6)

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I know the following can be the answer, but how to do it without using `\psgrid`?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(8,6)
\psgrid[style=gridstyle,gridlabels=0]   
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: if you do not want labels then it is a redefinition of the grid style and I cannot see  that this is a problem!

Comment: @Herbert: Redefinition wastes more keystrokes because many keys must be redefined to obtain the same settings that the original grid style settings has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}{gridlabels=0pt}
```

http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pst-news08.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I could probably write you a better answer if I understood better what you're trying to do.  But with that said, you could just use:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture*}[showgrid=bottom](8,6)

    \psline[linecolor=red](0,0)(8,6)

\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

The starred version of the environment gives you a clipped version.

[image]

But this solution assumes that there's nothing outside of the rectangle defined by `(0,0)` and `(8,6)` that you want to see.

Looking at the documentation in *pst-news05*, you can redefine the grid style that `showgrid` uses with the following line:

```
\newpsstyle{gridstyle}{subgriddiv=0,
                       gridcolor=lightgray,
                       griddots=10,
                       gridlabels=0pt}
```

I think this is probably preferable to clipping.  For example, if you pass `\psline[arrows=o-o](0,0)(8,6)` in the clipped version, you'll get something suboptimal.